# How to auto launch an application on an android event

Tags: android

I have an application which can explore the file system of android and the devices connected to android.
I want my app to get launched automatically on an event-specifically whenever a usb storage device is connected.

I have tried giving device filter list and it does the task but the application gets launched only for devices that are mentioned in the device filter list. How can I achieve the same for all usb devices-application should launch itself automatically for every usb device connected,

Comment: it is too broad to answer the whole process here, IMHO. Please refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html to set up USB Accessory mode

Comment: The link you mentioned talks about usb accessory mode of android. But in my case it is usb host mode